# Can't use vector of custom class objects in android native c++

Tags: android, c++, opencv, vector, android-ndk

I'm developing an image processing application using Opencv and android Ndk.
First I wrote my code in visual studio and there was no problem.
I have header roi.hpp and roi.cpp :
roi.hpp:

```
 #ifndef ROI 
 #define ROI


  #include <..\..\imgproc.hpp>
  #include <..\..\opencv.hpp>

  using namespace cv;

 class My_ROI{
   public:
    My_ROI();
    My_ROI(const My_ROI &my_roi);
    My_ROI(Point upper_corner, Point lower_corner,Mat src);
    Point upper_corner, lower_corner;
    Mat roi_ptr;
    Scalar color;
    int border_thickness;
    void draw_rectangle(Mat src);
};



#endif
```

roi.cpp:

```
              #include "myImage.hpp"
              #include <..\..\imgproc.hpp>
             #include <..\..\opencv.hpp>
             #include <..\..\highgui.hpp>
               #include <stdio.h>
              #include <stdlib.h>
             #include <string>
             #include "roi.hpp"

    using namespace cv;
   using namespace std;

  My_ROI::My_ROI(const My_ROI &my_roi)
     {
        int i;

       // allocate variables
        My_ROI();

        // copy values
            operator = (my_roi);
         }

     My_ROI::My_ROI(){
        upper_corner=Point(0,0);
        lower_corner=Point(0,0);

           }

        My_ROI::My_ROI(Point u_corner, Point l_corner, Mat src){
        upper_corner=u_corner;
        lower_corner=l_corner;
        color=Scalar(0,255,0);
        border_thickness=2;
        roi_ptr=src(Rect(u_corner.x, u_corner.y, l_corner.x- u_corner.x,l_corner.y-    u_corner.y));
      }

     void My_ROI::draw_rectangle(Mat src){
    rectangle(src,upper_corner,lower_corner,color,border_thickness);

    }
```

and in another class I made a vector of My_ROI and use it with no problem, Like this:

```
            vector <My_ROI> roi;
            for (int j = 0; j<NSAMPLES; j++){
            roi[j].draw_rectangle(m->src);
         }
```

Then I ported my project to android I use roi.hpp and roi.cpp as external c++ files ,this is my android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

 include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES := on 
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES := on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC

include ../../jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE := hello-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += ../../external_cpp/makegray.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += ../../external_cpp/roi.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../external_cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl



include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

application.mk:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

And finally in hello-jni.cpp file I want to use vector of roi:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


#include "../../external_cpp/roi.hpp"
 vector <My_ROI> roi;

void fillROIArray(MyImage *m,Mat& mRgb,Mat& mGray)
 {
m->src=mRgb;
    flip(m->src,m->src,1);//reverse the order of rows or cols in a matrix
//  My_ROI *f1 = new My_ROI;
//  roi.push_back(*f1);
    roi.push_back(My_ROI(Point(m->src.cols/3, m->src.rows/6),Point(m->src.cols/3+square_len,m->src.rows/6+square_len),m->src));
    roi.push_back(My_ROI(Point(m->src.cols/4, m->src.rows/2),Point(m->src.cols/4+square_len,m->src.rows/2+square_len),m->src));
    roi.push_back(My_ROI(Point(m->src.cols/3, m->src.rows/1.5),Point(m->src.cols/3+square_len,m->src.rows/1.5+square_len),m->src));
    roi.push_back(My_ROI(Point(m->src.cols/2, m->src.rows/2),Point(m->src.cols/2+square_len,m->src.rows/2+square_len),m->src));
    roi.push_back(My_ROI(Point(m->src.cols/2.5, m->src.rows/2.5),Point(m->src.cols/2.5+square_len,m->src.rows/2.5+square_len),m->src));
    roi.push_back(My_ROI(Point(m->src.cols/2, m->src.rows/1.5),Point(m- >src.cols/2+square_len,m->src.rows/1.5+square_len),m->src));
    roi.push_back(My_ROI(Point(m->src.cols/2.5, m->src.rows/1.8),Point(m->src.cols/2.5+square_len,m->src.rows/1.8+square_len),m->src));
    mGray=m->src;
}
    void myMethod(Image &m)
    {


    for (int j = 0; j<NSAMPLES; j++){
        roi[j].draw_rectangle(m->src);
    }

}
```

but it makes error :

```
 method draw_rectangle(...) couldn't be resolved!
```

I can access my roi object all members but when I make vector of this class I don't have access to its members!
I searched a lot about making vectors of custom class and It's several days I'm working to solve this problem but I couldn't.

any help really appreciate.
regards.

Comment: Where do you fill the vector?

Comment: in hello-jni.cpp file before myMethod() I fill the vector like this: roi.push_back(Point,Point,src);

Comment: What type is `m->src`?

Comment: In 'myMethod` the `roi` your using is empty, either use the one with something in it or push_back something in it for further testing.

Comment: It's not empty I edited the post .first I call fillROIArray then my method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found solution ... maybe it's usefull for others .
I can access to vector's members like this :

```
  for (int j = 0; j<NSAMPLES; j++){
    ((My_ROI)roi[j]).draw_rectangle(m->src);
}
```

I can access any vector's objects from any custom classes now ! :)